# Checar se git esta instalado usando Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

Estou iniciando em um aplicativo desktop com o uso de Electron contudo preciso verificar se há Git instalado no sistema pois o mesmo obrigatoriamente precisa usar `git`

Como a ideia é distribuir em Windows, Linux e Mac e a verificação deve ocorrer a cada "startup" do aplicativo como posso verificar isto em Linux e Mac?

O que tenho por hora:

```
const {
    spawn,
    spawnSync,
    exec,
    execSync,
    execFileSync,
} = require('child_process')

switch(process.platform){
    case'win32':
        let git = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'git --version'])
        git.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            // logic...
        });
        break;
    case'linux':
        //
        break;
    case'darwin':
        //
        break;
    default:
        // unsupported
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ainda não tive oportunidade para usar o Node e tudo mais, mas acho que você pode chamar o git direto, não precisa chamar o executável do shell para fazer isso.

```
let git = spawn('git', ['--version'])
```

Inclusive, para o que você quer, segundo o link que vou colocar na fonte, é mais usado o execFile para isso:

```
const child = execFile('git', ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
      console.error('stderr', stderr);
      throw error;
  }
  console.log('stdout', stdout);
});
```

> Quando?
>
> O execFile é usado quando precisamos apenas executar um aplicativo e
>   obter a saída. Por exemplo, podemos usar o execFile para executar um
>   aplicativo de processamento de imagem como o ImageMagick para
>   converter uma imagem de PNG para o formato JPG e nós só nos
>   preocupamos se ela for bem-sucedida ou não. ExecFile não deve ser
>   usado quando o aplicativo externo produz uma grande quantidade de
>   dados e precisamos consumir esses dados em tempo real.

## Fonte

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node

Answer (score 0):

A solução mais simples que pensei foi essa:

```
const platform = process.platform
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const where = platform === 'win32' ? 'where' : 'which'
const out = spawn(where, ['ls'])

out.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`) // 0 se o comando existe, 1 se não existe
});
```